# iOS WatchKit - How to add a row with multiple lines to WKInterfaceTable in Storyboard

Tags: ios, multiline, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I am trying to create a table that will have rows that contain 2 lines.
The top line will contain 2 Labels with 50% width each and the bottom line would have 1 slider with 100% width.

In storyboard, I can get the top line to have the 2 labels with 50% width each just fine, but whenever I add the slider, it always tries to attach it at the end of the top line instead of moving it down.

I have even sized the height for the cell properly, as well as tried playing with the alignments (left, center, right) on all objects. I even added an "adjustment" to the height of the slider thinking it would offset it to the 2nd line. Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add two groups to your row in the story board.  The outer most group should have vertical layout.  In that group you will put a group with horizontal layout at the top and the slider at the bottom.  The group with the horizontal layout will have the two labels in it.

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick. Totally missed the 'Layout' attribute in storyboard for WKInterfaceGroup. Changed that to vertical and now allows me to stack items.